# Newly created "query rule" only takes effect in a few search result

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search, query-rule

SP2013, onprem, farm solution:

I have created a new Query rule, with help from [this guide](http://stevemannspath.blogspot.se/2013/03/sharepoint-2013-adding-people-to.html). It seems to work like a charm on my dev machine, but on production it only takes effect in a few search result. The main purpose is having the horizontal people-search hit above the search result and below the search-textbox. This works ok, but I have a new display template instead of Item_Person_CompactHorizontal.html. In most of my search hits I get the old template and in a very few hits (typing in random letters in search box, like 'G', I get exactly the result I get. Im currently not in a position where I can reset index and recrawl Everything (unless I know it will work)

Hope this was somewhat understandable, if not, please ask :)

EDIT: It seems that I get my display template when I get a single people result (one person), but If I get more I always get the existing/old one

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the "Item_Person_CompactHorizontal.html" contained two views, one for "single person result" and one for "multiple person results", so after modifying both views it worked...yeeey!

ok... I cant accept this answer for two more days and Ill probalby forget to do so, but consider it accepted by me